# $\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} \binom{m+n-i}{k-i} = \binom mk$

Tags: combinatorics

$\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} \binom{m+n-i}{k-i} = \binom mk$  for $m\ge k,$ 
and it is equal to 0 if $m < k$.

I was asked to use the inclusion-exclusion principle to give a combinatorial proof.

What should I do for this equation?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: You have $m$ cats and $n$ dogs in a room, and you want to choose from them a group consisting of $k$ cats. There are $\binom{m+n}k$ ways to choose a group of $k$ animals from those in the room. There are $\binom{n}1$ ways to choose one dog and then $\binom{m+n-1}{k-1}$ ways to choose another $k-1$ animals; each of these groups of $k$ animals is guaranteed to contain a dog and so must be subtracted from the preliminary count of $\binom{m+n}k$ ways. Of course this subtracts too much, since any group of $k$ animals containing at least $2$ dogs gets subtracted at least twice, so we have to compensate by adding those groups back in.

Can you see how to finish it off with the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) from this setup?

Comment: Basically whenever we are considering first $\binom{n}{0}$$\binom{m+n}{k}$, we are considering all possible cases of choosing $k$ animals out of $m+n$ ones. Now we substract $\binom{n}{1}$$\binom{m+n-1}{k-1}$ i.e. we remove all cases such that atleast 1 dog occurs and hence we ensure now only cases are there where there is no dogs in the choosen ways. Now whenever we add $\binom{n}{2}$$\binom{m+n-2}{k-2}$ to this, it counts all the cases where there are 0 dogs or more than 2 dogs. Similarly, substracting $\binom{n}{3}$$\binom{m+n-1}{k-1}$ gives cases where exactly 0 or 2 dogs are there. Right?

Comment: Then how do we get at the final step that after i many steps, exactly 0 dogs are choosen. Because what i get here is that whenever I substract $\binom{n}{j}$$\binom{m+n-j}{k-j}$, only even no of dogs are remaining in our choices and whenever I add $\binom{n}{j+1}$$\binom{m+n-j-1}{k-j-1}$, we are taking cases where upto a certain even no, only even dogs are getting counted and after that all possible ways to get atleast those many dogs are counted. [exactly what we describes fr j = 2].. P.S. there is some mistake in my understanding for sure as this can be proved algebraically.  any insights?